# Hide a face of a 3D shape behind another, Android canvas?

Tags: android, 3d, rotation, android-canvas

Suppose that I have to draw two faces of a 3D shape in a canvas. In OpenGL, we use clockwise and non clockwise ordering of vertices to detect what face is front face and what is behind face, but *I can not use OpenGL* and I would to use canvas. It seems that if we draw behind face and then draw front face, it hides behind face, but my 3D shape rotates and each face some times must be front and some times must be behind.

My question is: When shape is rotating, how I can detect witch face is front? Or any other way to hide current behind face with front face?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process you describe is called *back-face culling* (this will greatly improve your google prowess on the topic).

The straight forward way to implement is to take the `normal vector` of your `face`, and check if it faces towards or away from the camera.

You do this using the `dot product` of the `normal` and the `view vector` of your camera. Depending on the `sign` of the dot product, the polygon is facing towards or away from the camera.

If you don't actually have a camera at this point, substitute a vector into the screen (i.e. `[0, 0, 1]` or `[0, 0, -1]` depending on your axis system).

Comment: @Pau-Jan How I can take the normal of the face?

Comment: You pick 3 distinct vertices v1, v2, v3 (if your face is a triangle, simply take those 3 vertices), then use the crossproduct (v2 - v1) x (v3 - v1) and normalize. Warning: this is really fundamental 3D stuff, if you do not know this by heart you definitely should get a good textbook before undertaking something as complex as software rendering.

Comment: @Pau-Jal Thank you for your attention.I know that if we can normalize the result of outer product(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of two vector in a plane.But my problem is that I can not get points in rotated face.The matrix in canvas,is not really a transformation matrix in 3D space.It maps 2D points to another 2D points as we imagine that our face is translated or rotated  in 3D space.Do you any Idea about this,please tell me.

Comment: Aha. Unfortunately I now now longer have no clue what you are doing :-). Indeed, the default Matrix of the Android canvas is a 2D transformation matrix. However, you are talking about a `rotating 3D shape` in your problem description, so I was hoping I could assume you have 3D vertices at that point. If that was a wrong assumption, you are definitely going to have to post some code illustrating the concepts of "3D shape", "Rotation" and "Projection".

Comment: I asked another question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/276982/21779) ,that is correspond to current question.I will be glad if you guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you looking for 3D Flipping?
If so, then I suggest you look at [this link](http://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/) and [this one](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html).
Also there is some other related questions on StackOverFlow and other blogs. Just search "*3D Flip on Android*" on Google.

Good luck!