# Transformation Matrix in Android Canvas?

Tags: android, matrix, android-canvas, transformation

This question is following up my previous question: [Hide a face of a 3D shape behind another, Android canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13899774/1043882)

I have a canvas and I have to get the normal vector of a face after rotating it via a matrix that is earned by `graphics.Camera`. From Mathematics, we know that transformation matrix of  `Translation`, `Rotation` and `Scaling` are `orthogonal`, and [preserve angles](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/265882/21779). So when I do some rotation by Camera and get it's matrix via `Camera.getMatrix(Matrix matrix)`, I expected that matrix must be `orthogonal` because the official document says:

> public void getMatrix (Matrix matrix)  Since: API Level 1
>   Computes
>   the matrix corresponding to the current **transformation** and copies it
>   to the supplied matrix object.

If it was really orthogonal matrix, I could translate normal vector of the face (before rotating it) by matrix that is gotten from Camera and result will be parallel to normal vector of face after rotating it. But when I multiply that matrix to its transpose, the result matrix is not identical.
Now my question is:

Does `getMatrix (Matrix matrix)` really return the matrix corresponding to the current **transformation**? If it is true, why when I multiply the returned matrix to its transpose, result is not identical?